# Forum on synthetic biology and hypothetical biology?

Tags: synthetic-biology, speculative

I am interested in synthetic biology, but not a scientist, and would like some advice on where to look for an online forum on synthetic biology and creating fictional species and animals or if someone could suggest the best website to set such a forum up on.

The current research into synthetic biology with biobricks and all the complicated discussion of biochemistry and genetics is too advanced for myself and not what I am interested in. I have fictional ideas of how to create new organisms and symbiotic organisms that are designed and grown for humans to wear and utilise and would like to bounce ideas off other people who may be in to the same area - the potential application of synthetic biology in the far future.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: what you ask for is not synthetic biology but science fiction. [SF&F-SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) would be a suitable forum for this kind of discussion.

Comment: Synthetic biology is currently at the level of constructing genetic circuits and modifying bacteria. We still don't fully understand all the details of how single-cell organisms work, so creating new types of animals is pretty far away.

Comment: What you want is not a forum on synthetic biology, rather a science fiction site. I recommend visiting the sister website found in https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com which is a "is a question and answer site for writers, artists and others using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings." I am positive that you will find intriguing discussions on synthetic biology there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be the sub forum on reddit specialized in synthetic biology. Have a look [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Synthetic_Biology/)

Happy science!